# Can foreign keys be null?

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, relationship

I have a situation where accounts can have many phone numbers, but phone numbers can only be assigned to one account. This would normally be considered a one-to-many relationship, but the phone numbers in the application may remain unassigned for a period of time (which means the account foreign key would be absent until assigned to a different account).

I feel like the relationships should be managed through a join table, simply because a phone number may not be assigned to an account for a period of time.

Is a join table the right option, or is it okay for a foreign key to be blank?

Edit: essentially, I have a table of phone numbers and a table of accounts. Accounts can have many phone numbers, but phone numbers may only be assigned to one account at any particular time. There will be times when phone numbers will NOT be assigned to an account.

Comment: Its unclear from your question if you have a list/bank of defined telephone numbers that may only be assigned to a single account or if the telephone can be any valid number as provided by the telecommunications company. If you could clarify that would help with providing a good answer.

Comment: @armitage I have a list/bank of telephone numbers that can only be assigned to a single account. Sorry I didn't clarify that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to have another indirection table for users/phones unless the relationship is many-to-many.  It would be better to just have the user key on the phones table be `null` when no user consumes it and have the number itself be unique.

Comment: This was my first thought, but I didn't know if it was considered bad practice to have a `null` foreign key. Thanks for the help!